# How Can I Have Lists that Expand on Drag like Notifications?

Tags: android, list, notifications, drag, expand

I have a list of items (I'm currently using recyclerview). I want to be able to show one item and then expand the list on drag in the same layered way that notifications expand when dragged from the status bar. For instance:

[image]

I could program a bunch of individual views and hold them in a list array and probably use animation and such on each individually, but I'm hoping there's a more established way of doing this. Any ideas?